# Are there different types of HTML closing tags

Tags: javascript, html, xss

Recently I came across this type of tag in an HTML:
`` <x/ id="someId" onpointermove=alert`hello`> ``

This data was fetched from the server as a JSON and then written into the HTML view.
The HTML view displays the data with no issues.
However, on running the request that just fetches the data in a new tab, the Javascript code is running.

How is this code running?

I just know this type of self closing tag: `<x id="someId" />`.
So, what is this different type of tag I encountered?

Also, is this another way of using the back tick?

I initially thought it was a type of string interpolation. But I could not find any reference to this particular type of code in it.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: It'd say this is either broken code or an attempt to abuse a XSS vulnerability :-?

Comment: it's not valid HTML. since you saw it in a JSON message, it could be undergoing any number of transformations before it gets injected into the DOM, meaning what you've posted here might not be the final form. putting a slash after the tag name is not valid HTML.

Comment: More details needed. How is it "written into an HTML view"? What does it actually render? Can you post more of the code?

Comment: </x> is definitely not valid html. Here is a full list of valid html tags: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_html_dtd.asp

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález this was done to check XSS vulnerability. But I am not familiar with this syntax. Is there some article/doc that you could recommend for more information?

Comment: @LionelRowe the data is getting rendered in the HTML view properly. Its only when running the request on its own that this script activates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's deliberately incorrect HTML syntax - you can verify this by pasting it (with the necessary boilerplate, below) into [the W3 HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>a</title>
</head>
<body>
  <x/ id="someId" onpointermove=alert`hello`>
</body>
</html>
```

This gives several validation errors.

*However*, unlike XML, HTML is very forgiving. It'll do its best to render *something*, even if what it's given is very obviously wrong. There are complex rules about how it goes about doing this, but these days it's *almost* always at least consistent between modern browsers (and if it's not, that's due to bugs, rather than differences of opinion between vendors).

In this case, what it renders actually resolves to the following `outerHTML`:

```html
<x id="someId" onpointermove="alert`hello`">
</x>
```

Malformed syntax like this is often used to deliberately test the limits of XSS prevention, because XSS prevention might perceive it as "safe", even though browsers will actually render something dangerous.

Of particular interest here is `` alert`hello` `` - backticks are another way of getting JavaScript to call functions, *without using parentheses*. This is due to how [tagged template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates) work. So an out-of-date or buggy XSS sanitizer might perceive `` alert`hello` `` as "safe" because it doesn't contain any function calls (determined by absence of parentheses), yet actually it still executes `alert`.

Comment: Thx for the link pointing to the correct part of the doc. I had read right through it and missed looking carefully at the template example.